# Очень медленно выполняется метод веб-сервиса из C#

Tags: c#

Есть консольное приложение написанное на C#. В Visual Studio добавил ссылку на веб-сервис wsdl. После запуска приложения вызывается метод веб-сервиса и результат его выполнения появляется через 11-17 секунд. Далее, если в приложении указать еще раз выполнить этот метод, то вызов пройдет за 2 секунды. Проверил wireshark`ом, что происходит в момент запуска. После запуска приложения соединение с веб-сервисом происходит только через 10-12 секунд, и после соединения метод выполняется за 2 секунды. Какая процедура может занимать 10 секунд при вызове метода в первый раз?

```
CrmMethods createFL = new CrmMethods();
Console.WriteLine("run method");
var response = createFL.CreatePerson();
Console.WriteLine(response.ReturnCode.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
//второй раз метод выполняется за 2 секунды.
 Console.WriteLine("run method");
var response = createFL.CreatePerson();
Console.WriteLine(response.ReturnCode.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

P.S. на английском форуме нашел статьи про proxy, но у меня не используется прокси.

Comment: Может dns тупит? Что если по IP попробовать к сервису подключиться.

Comment: `Какая процедура может занимать 10 секунд при вызове метода в первый раз` поднятие сервиса, IIS примерно столько и поднимает пулл

Comment: @iluxa1810 собственно по ip и подключаюсь

Comment: @tCode веб-сервис на tomcat развернут. Там тоже есть такое? Странно, что tcp соединение моя станция устанавливает только спустя 10 секунд и через 2 метод выполняется.

Comment: @AndreySherman а аутентификация в сервисе есть? С первым запросом может выполняться аутентификация.

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, аутентификация есть.

Comment: @tCode где-то прочитал: "что по умолчанию необходимо скомпилировать XmlSerializer для веб-службы, для последующих вызовов этого не требуется."

Comment: @AndreySherman Она небось еще виндовая? В общем, мне кажется, что дело в аутентификации.

Comment: я бы смотрел на настройки сервиса, если к ним есть доступ. Сомневаюсь что Tomcat не пользуется возможностью выгрузить сервис на время простоя, если иное не указано в настройках приложения явно. В IIS у нас была такая проблема, решаем принудительной настройкой сервера не выгружать приложение во время простоя, если время первичного отклика является критичным, а частота обращений к сервису низкая.

Comment: @iluxa1810 даже для авторизации через kerberos 10-12 сек это очень много, вряд ли, хотя я знаю пару способов получить такое время даже для basic-авторизации =) не для применения естественно.

Comment: @rdom ну у коллеги была как то проблема с корпоративном сайтом, который юзал виндовую аутентификации и каждый запрос выполнялся долго. Проблема была в том что запрос к домен контроллеру по кривом маршруту ходил